# Creating browser macro to autmate navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Is it possible to create javascript function in browsers developer console that will listen to for specific key and then execute another JS script that is also prepared in advance?

I also wounder is there a way for this functions to live after new page is loaded?

I'd prefer not using extensions if there is a way.

Comment: When a page is loaded, all javascript is reset.  This includes anything entered in the console.  You could add your code to a bookmark then click the bookmark on the new page.

Comment: I understand it probably is like this because of browsers safety. And that if you can make functions like this it would expose users privacy in many ways. But still, gotta ask.